# Circuit for DFT transform?

Tags: signal, fourier, fft, compression

In my recent project I need to apply DFT to signal and find it's coefficient values.

Can you please suggest any circuit/chip which can perform DFT/FFT transform on analog signals?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing any of the demands on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, there are basically two categories of methods to choose from.

The pure electronic approach is to use banks of very tight filters to provide you with magnitude estimates of the frequencies of interest.  The more frequencies you need, the more circuit you need to build.  An analogous approach would be to use a very tight filter that's tunable, like a lock-in amp, to do the same thing, sweeping through the frequency spectrum.  You lose phase information by either method.

The other class of method is to sample the signal, and mathematically do the transform with computational power.  This is probably the way to go.  The accessible paths here are to a) use a fancy microcontroller with some digital signals processing capabilities, like the STM32F4 ARM Cortex, or to do this with a full computer with an operating system.  If you go the full computer route, you can still implement this on a small board by using a single board computer like the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  The advantages of doing this are that the environment you work in will be very much like a classical computing environment, and its probably the fastest way to go if you're starting from scratch.  That said, if you're starting from scratch and don't have a solid computing background, I suggest this will take you between one and three months of pretty hard work.

There may be a way to accomplish what you need to do faster.  For example, if you're only interested in one or two frequencies that will never change and don't care about phase, just use tight filters.  We can't help you narrow down your problem if you don't tell us what it is.